# How to get the sum of tokens on all Ethereum addresses generated by one private key?

Tags: erc-20, hd-wallets

I need a tool that automatically show all wallet addresses generated with one private key. Ideally, it would be to manage tokens on any of the addresses from one place.
This is implemented in the web version of MEW, but it is very inconvenient, perhaps there are some other wallets with this functionality.

Comment: I noticed that I received an anonymous payment of Tron in my Ether wallet, and for some reason, this Tron now held in the overall wallet is not even given a total valuation, i.e. no sum, just the number of tokens only. is this normal, because it would definitely affect what you're trying to do

Comment: a private key can have only 1 address. Please edit your question so it has truthful statements

Answer (score 2):

Hope you are talking aboug HD wallets, In order to get addresses generated from a "Mnemonics" or "seed" , You have to keep track of "address index", Usually it starts from 0. With every incremented value you will get a new hd wallet address get derived from the "Mnemonics" or "Seed".

For example:

```
function getBTCAddress(mnemonics, addressIndex) {

  var seed = await bip39.mnemonicToSeed(mnemonics);
  const root = await bip32.fromSeed(seed, pubKeyHash);

  // Child address derivation path
  const derivePath = selectDerivationPath(network);
  const child = root.derivePath(derivePath + addressIndex);

  // Child address public/private keys
  const getChildPk = bip32.fromBase58(child.toBase58(), pubKeyHash);
  const childAddress = getAddress(child, pubKeyHash);
  const childPrivateKey = getChildPk.toWIF();

  // Master private key root.toWIF()

  const obj = {
    address: childAddress.toString(),
    privatekey: childPrivateKey,
    index: addressIndex
  }     
 return obj;
}
```

Comment: Sure, I use HD wallet solution (BTCPay server with Ethereum plugin) and it generate new address for any new payment, so I need "command center" to operate all the generated addresses.